# Why bootstrapper project is not starting using owin Startup?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin

I have an ASP.NET MVC project, created in Visual Studio. I am using an onion architecture. I am trying to use owin to start my project.

Here is my project structure:

I have

```
Camelrace.core
Camelrace.services
Camelrace.Bootstrapper
Camelrace.Data
Camelrace.Web
```

Under bootstrapper project, I have the startup class:

```
public partial class Startup
{
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
            ConfigureMvcAndWebApi();
        }
}
```

In the

```
 public void ConfigureMvcAndWebApi()
        {
            MvcConfig.ConfigureMvc(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
```

In the configureMVC, I am adding the routes:

```
public static void ConfigureMvc(RouteCollection routes)
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
    routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "News", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new[] { "CamelRace.Web.Controllers" }
            );
}
```

Whenever I start the project and put a break point in the `ConfigureMvcAndWebApi` method, nothing happens. Which means my project is not bootstrapped properly.

When I hit F5 I get:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Any reason for this?

Comment: So your default route defines the `NewsController` and its `Index` action method as startup default - do you **have** a `NewsController` and does it **have** an `Index` action method??

Comment: @marc_s yes I do hve

Comment: @marc_s the MvcConfig class is in the web project and I reference the web dll in the bootstrapper project

Comment: @marc_s any luck boss

Comment: @marc_s any response sir